# Recommended way to run Internet Explorer on a Mac

Tags: macos, internet-explorer

What is the recommended way to run Internet Explorer on a Mac? My preferences are:

- preferably free (like free speech) software
- preferably free (no cost) software
- possibility to run different versions of Explorer

The goal is to have it, as many do, just to test developed web assets in IE.

Comment: Use a virtual machine.  Microsoft offers a free virtual machine in every major virtual machine format and every possible IE combination.  IE has not been a native version of a Apple OS for over a decade.

Comment: first: why you comment and not answer instead? second: the whole question is all about which virtual machine to use

Comment: You made no mention of the fact you wanted to use a virtual machine. As for a product recomendation that won't happen. Microsoft provides virtual machines for all three major solutions. 66% of those solutions can be used on OS X

Comment: i do not *want* to use a virtual machine, it is just common knownledge that it is the way to go. i wanted to keep the question open, but my *personal* opinion is that a virtual machine is better. you keep commenting instead of answering. are you saying that microsoft provides its own virtual machines? or it provides just the virtualised images?

Comment: Microsoft provides both. The reason I am not providing an answer to this question because **this question is not clear**.  There really are only two solutions.  THe first is Bootcamp and a Windows installation which limits you to certain versions of IE.  THe second solution is to use a virtual machine and one of Microsoft's virtual machine images it provides in ALL virtual machine major formats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look here: http://www.modern.ie/en-us
Here you can download a virtual machine for testing purposes

Comment: link is dead : '(

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer is not supported on mac anymore, but there is a way to run it. You can use [WineBottler](http://winebottler.kronenberg.org/). Install X11. Start WineBottler and Click on Install Predefined Prefixes. Select the software and install.

Comment: from the name, i think that this is based upon wine, which is usually not a recommended way to run explorer for development. for example i imagine that it could get complicated to maintain different versions of explorer with that system

Answer (score 0):

Install BootCamp with a version of Windows.  That way you can run IE in its native environment.  Or, invest in a cheap Windows computer (could be had for roughly $200).

Comment: thanks, i did not know bootcamp, i was back in time on parallels ...